# Does Ispell send any of the checked data to a server?

Tags: linux, macos, emacs

Does Ispell only use local dictionaries, or does it send any of the checked data to a server?

The best answer I can find is that it is up to the implementation, and the only open-source repository I can find is the Debian version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original version of Ispell was written in assembler and
dates to 1971, and it never used any cloud servers
(the cloud didn't exist then). It was later rewritten in C

Ispell only uses local dictionaries. You may consult them on the page
[Dictionaries for International Ispell](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/%7Egeoff/ispell-dictionaries.html).
You need to download and install a dictionary on your computer
locally for Ispell to be able to use it.

Reference : [Wikipedia Ispell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ispell).